# Firebase Phone Auth is not working version 20.0.0 in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I did update the firebase dependency to latest version as per [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Old dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.7.1'
```

Updated dependencies

```
   //firebase
    //By using the Firebase Android BoM, your app will always use compatible versions of the Firebase Android libraries.
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    //The Firebase Authentication Android library now works on devices without Google Play services.
//    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0"
```

old phone auth method works fine

```
   PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            activity,
            this
        )
```

But,after updated the dependency above method shows deprecated.so,tried this

```
         val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                .setPhoneNumber("+1 5123456788")
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setActivity(this)
                .build()
            PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
        }
```

This error occurs when build method is called.

```
2020-10-29 16:14:57.406 3422-3422/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm, PID: 3422
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions$Builder.build(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:22)
        at com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm.MainActivity$onPostCreate$2.onClick(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7861)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7830)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:878)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29354)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2020-10-29 16:14:57.428 3422-3422/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm I/Process: Sending signal.
```

This error occured after i added the callbacks

```
2020-10-30 10:47:34.239 24898-24898/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm, PID: 24898
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:92)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onPostExecute(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:88)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm-Cn_en1RDZ9XDneMCJamrPw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm-Cn_en1RDZ9XDneMCJamrPw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:92) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:79) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onPostExecute(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:88) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
2020-10-30 10:47:34.314 24898-24898/com.gowtham.firebasephoneauthwithmvvm I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24898 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can u try without actual phone number?

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: This error occurs when i call build()

Comment: Now i've added the full error log @AlexMamo

Comment: @AmodGokhale I tried with my test device number as well

Comment: Any working solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malcolm from Firebase here!

It looks like you're missing a set of `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` - please call [`#setCallbacks()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#setCallbacks(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)) on your `Builder`.

I'll see if we can't get that error message to be less cryptic

Comment: Thanks..it's solved that issue.but,I got another error seems it is related to reCaptcha verification.I've updated the error in my question.can u check it

Comment: Thanks again.last error solved by adding implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'.

Comment: Is there any alternative to prevent opening the browser for verification? Just asking from a UX perspective. If so, can you please elucidate? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah - enable the SafetyNet API as described here:
https://firebase.devsite.corp.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

Comment: Malcolm I am unable to navigate to the given link as it requires login credentials

Answer (score 6):

According to the Firebase Phone-Auth [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=1#enable-app-verification), you need to enable **reCAPTCHA verification**

Start by adding `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'` at build.gradle (module app) dependencies

This will make firebase to open the browser for reCAPTCHA verification.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions work pretty fine i.e., adding the implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0' at build.gradle (module app) dependency, but another error occurs that it only runs on api 26 or higher.

Adding

```
android{
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

at build.gradle (module app) will help with lower api.